# FindDuplicatesByIds Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to write TriggerHandlerClass that marks a checkbox as 'true' whenever an account is considered 'duplicate'.

Here is my code thus far for the Handler class:

```
public with sharing class isduplicateclass {
    public void updateDup(List<Account> acts) {
        
        List<id> idList = new List<id>();
        List<Account> updateActs = new List<Account>();

        for(Account a : [SELECT ID, Is_duplicate__c, Type FROM Account]){
        idList.add(a.id);
            if (Datacloud.FindDuplicatesByIds.findDuplicatesByIds(idList).size() > 0) {
                a.Is_duplicate__c = true;
                updateActs.add(a);

            }
        }
    UPDATE updateActs;
    }
}
```

My logic here is that the Trigger should iterate through each Account, add each Account ID to the 'idList' list, then, if the ID of each Account is larger than 0, turn 'Is_duplicate_c' to true, add the accounts to the 'updateActs' list, then update the Accounts.

I am currently getting the error: maximum trigger depth exceeded.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: That error occurs if there is any recursion possibility, what does "Datacloud.FindDuplicatesByIds.findDuplicatesByIds(idList)" hold or is it some logic which triggers on record save? 

If its something run on record save you can have the logic to identify duplicate there in that class or if the logic is based on few fields that you identify the records duplicate you can query basd on those values and check if the records exists, if it does mark it as duplicate else not.

Comment: Hey Praveenkumar, I found "Datacloud.FindDuplicatesByIds.findDuplicatesByIds(idList)": https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicatesByIds.htm. From my understanding, the output of FindDuplicatesByIds is an array of objects with the same number of elements as the input array, and in the same order. The output objects encapsulate record IDs for duplicate records.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here.

First is that you're calling findDuplicatesByIds inside a loop which is not a good idea.

Second is that you are not checking the current field value to see if it needs to be updated. This is causing all duplicates to be updated, which sends them right back to this code over and over. This is why you're getting 'maximum trigger depth exceeded'.

Third is that you are querying all accounts for no reason and not making use of the trigger's record collection (acts) at all.

Here is how I would handle it:

```
public void updateDup(List<Account> acts) {

    List<Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult> findDupeResults = 
        Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates(acts);

    Integer index = 0;
    List<Account> updateActs = new List<Account>();
    for (Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult findDupeResult : findDupeResults) {
        Account act = acts[index++];
        Boolean isDuplicate = false;
        for (Datacloud.DuplicateResult dupeResult : findDupeResult.getDuplicateResults()) {
            for (Datacloud.MatchResult matchResult : dupeResult.getMatchResults()) {
                isDuplicate = true;
            }
        }
        if (act.Is_duplicate__c != isDuplicate) {
            act.Is_duplicate__c = isDuplicate;
            updateActs.add(act);
        }
    }
    //if (!updateActs.isEmpty()) update updateActs;

}
```

EDIT: I would move this to a BEFORE INSERT / BEFORE UPDATE trigger and remove the call to 'update updateActs'. It would perform better that way, and there's no chance for recursion.

Comment: `if (!updateActs.isEmpty())` is no longer necessary in Apex.

Comment: I know but I still use it every time.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I appreciate your response and solution. I've got this working now, and am just going through and studying everything over to make sure I have it down. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If this is triggered by BEFORE INSERT or BEFORE UPDATE, then simply remove the call to UPDATE updateActs.

Calling update on records passed in a BEFORE INSERT or BEFORE UPDATE trigger causes an infinite recursion.

Further, any changes made to field values in a BEFORE INSERT or BEFORE UPDATE trigger are automatically saved to the record so there's no need to call update again.

Comment: Hey Bill, this is an after insert/ after update trigger

Comment: In that case, add a check the field to see if the field needs to be set. If it's already set to true, then there's no need to set it again and send the record back through the update triggers.
if (!a.Is_duplicate__c) {
    a.Is_duplicate__c = true;
    updateActs.add(a);
}

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE), Bill! To make it easier for future readers to see all the juicy info in one place, rather than putting additional information in the comments, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/372182/edit) your answer to add info and/or update after getting feedback from the OP. (Or to add/update for whatever reason.) Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Thanks Moonpie. I would have simply edited the answer, but I felt it would be misleading since it would change the context of the answer. Instead, I made a short comment here then posted a new answer.